# Using ZADD with option flag

Tags: go, redis

I am trying to add a record with a score into the sorted set if the record does not exist in the first place:

```golang
func (r *rDA) InsertIntoSortedSetIfNotExist(value int32, score int32) error {
    conn, err := r.pool.GetContext(r.ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    _, err = conn.Do("ZADD NX", "some_key", score, value)  // err = "ERR command 'ZADD NX' is not supported."
    return err
}
```

However this doesn't work with the error saying `ZADD NX` is not supported.

I tried this and it doesn't work as well:

```golang
_, err = conn.Do("ZADD", "some_key", score, value, "NX")  // err = "ERR syntax error"
```

Would appreciate if anyone knows how to use ZADD NX command using redigo. Thanks!

Comment: Try conn.Do("ZADD", "some_key", "NX",score, value)

Comment: So, you have tried `conn.Do("ZADD", "NX", "some_key", score, value)`, and it does not work?

Comment: @kostix Nope that returns syntax error as well

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Yup that exact line works. Didn't know the NX flag needs to be placed right there... Thanks!

Comment: @balaorang I have added a detailed answer based on my comment, Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to wrong placement of NX

```
conn.Do("ZADD", "some_key", "NX",score, value)
```

The command for redis is used like this for NX

```
ZADD NAME NX 2 'Jhon'
```

You can also checkout the documentation at https://redis.io/commands/zadd#zadd-options-redis-302-or-greater

> ZADD supports a list of options, specified after the name of the key
> and before the first score argument.